# Cumulocity IoT warning for bricklet ID #2131 (Illuminance bricklet)

Tags: cumulocity

I have a few TinkerForge sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi. I have humidity and barometer bricklets and almost everything is working fine. The only exception is for a single sensor: the Illuminance bricklet. For this there is no data sent to Cumulocity. The TinkerForge demo application works perfectly and displays luminosity values, so the sensor is producing data properly. But the Agent is not recognizing this sensor, or this type of sensor. The log contains the following warning:

> Jun 17 15:12:51 raspberrypi root: 15:12:51.719 [Callback-Processor] WARN  c8y.tinkerforge.Discoverer - Unsuported device identifier: 2131

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Some bricklets are just not supported.

I downloaded the [source code for the Cumulocity Agent](https://github.com/thecreator007/c8y-Agent-Java) (written in Java) and I browsed through it and I found out that the Illuminance bricklet is not listed.

Until Cumulocity updates their agent, it just won't work.

If and when this happens, I will update this answer.